# Custom style sheet - css

Tags: css, custom, style

I've created a custom CSS file and added it to a Style Library. In my Master page I've referenced it. I am enable to see the styles from the CSS file because i am in the SharePoint Owner group. However, users in the custom Sharepoint Groups are unable to see the styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the location you saved the css file requires the document to be checked in and approved. Check that it is version 1.0 and approved.

Comment: Yes, it works. (I am new to SharePoint)